# nginx config for using plesk in docker environment

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, plesk

Currently I'm using docker containers to host several sites. With [jwilders nginx proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) i'm handling domains to my docker containers. My next step is to run [Plesk](https://hub.docker.com/r/plesk/plesk/) in a docker container, too. But i don't want to manually add every domain used within Plesk to my Plesk container (-e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com).

**Question**: Is it possible to set my Plesk container as fallback/default container for handling domains? If a domain is not a VIRTUAL_HOST it is handled by my Plesk-container and the nginx inside my Plesk-container can handle the domain.

`docker run -d -p 80:80 jwilder/nginx-proxy
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -e VIRTUAL_HOST=foo.bar.com someimage
docker run -d -it -p 8081:80 plesk/plesk`